Flutter internationalization in a package is not working
I am trying to split the code into different packages in the app I am currently programming. (comming from an C#/WPF environment and wanting to restrict "who can use which code" this seems right to me) Accordingly, I have also created a package in which I manage the .dart files with the view or the widgets (name: presentation). Now I would like to support several languages in my app and store the texts in an .arb file. I have followed the documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-internationalization/internationalization and created the files in my package (l10n.yaml in the package root, lib/l10n folder in lib of the package and the “flutter_gen” folder is also displayed in the .dart_tool folder of the package after the build. Now I want to add the import
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

When I build the app if get the following error:
presentation/lib/providers/multi_provider_builder.dart:13:8: Error: Error when reading '../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_gen-5.7.0/lib/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart': Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.

import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
       ^
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Has anyone tried to add the .arb files to a package?
My package “presentation” is inside the folder of the app. Mabye my app structure is the problem here? Example:

App

lib

main.dart


pubspec.yaml (of App)
presentation (package)

lib
// dart files and folders
pubsepc.yaml (of package with the installed flutter_localizations + intl)





Following the documentation in an Test app resulted in a working app but not with the packages structure I wanted to use
